# D3 rendering map not completely

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to follow a simple example to create a choropleth map of population density, like this [Mike Bostock’s Block 6320825](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6320825).

For this purpose I converted a relatively large (~35MB, [German postal areas](https://github.com/DerSpiegel/datenlese/blob/master/Betongold/PLZ_regions_Germany.geojson)) `geojson` file to `topojson` and added population data. In the code, I calculate population density on the fly and `.map` this data to the topojson as `properties`.

[image]

Problem is, not the whole map is rendered, there are always parts of it missing. Rendering just the outlines works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/* CSS goes here. */
.plzRegions {
  fill: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

/* JavaScript goes here. */
var width = 960;
    height = 1160;

// color scale
var color = d3.scale.log()
    .range(["hsl(62,100%,90%)", "hsl(228,30%,20%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

// projection and re-aligning
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([10, 51])
    .scale(1200 * 4)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// load topojson
d3.json("PLZ_GER_topo.json", function(error, ger){
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(ger);

    var plzRegions = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.PLZ_EWZ_Germany).features;

// calculate population density and map to topojson
    var densities = plzRegions
        .map(function(d) { return d.properties.dichte = d.properties.ewz / (d3.geo.area(d) / 12.56637 * 510072000); })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });

    color.domain([d3.quantile(densities, .01), d3.quantile(densities, .99)]);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "plzRegions")
      .selectAll("path")
        .data(plzRegions)
      .enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.properties.dichte); })
        .attr("d", path);
});

</script>
```

Maybe it's a problem with asynchronous data calculation and rendering, but looking at the `console.log`, density calculation seems to go fine.

Any advice is much appreciated!

**Update**

["Working" example](http://kuntzsch.me/maps/population)

Comment: Could you show us your topoJSON with the population data in it? At least seeing one area, that works, as well as one, which does not work, would be very helpful. If possible, set up a [mcve] to play around with.

Comment: Your data snippet includes Dresden and Köln, which—looking at the map—seem to be within the areas drawn correctly... What about Hannover?

Comment: @altocumulus Sadly, Dresden is not rendered correctly. I added a working example, which might be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed it, for most part at least. I just ran the file through [Mapshaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper), no simplification at all. There are still 2-3 holes, but that's probably due to topology errors in the [original file](https://github.com/DerSpiegel/datenlese/tree/master/Betongold).

```
npm install -g mapshaper
mapshaper -i PLZ_regions_Germany.geojson -simplify visvalingam 1.0 -o format=topojson new_map.json
```